# Check if combination of field data exist when submitting a form

Tags: python, django, forms

I want my form to check if the same name and date already exists in the postgresql so it does not produce a duplicate.

models.py:

```
class Event(models.Model):
  week = models.DateField(blank=False)
  name = models.ForeignKey(Employee, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  sunday = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True)
  monday = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  tuesday = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  wednesday = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  thursday = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  friday = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  saturday = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.week
```

views.py:

```
def test2(request):
  locationList = Location.objects.all().order_by('name') #Pulls location data from location table
  clientList = Client.objects.all().order_by('name') #Pull client data from client table

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form1 = EventForm2(request.POST) #Displays form to be filled out by user
    if form1.is_valid():
      event = form1.save() #Saves form if valid data is entered
      messages.info(request, 'Successfully added')
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('test2')) #Refreshes page to default
    else:
      form1 = EventForm2() #Form remains the same until valid data has been entered
      eventList = Event.objects.all().order_by('week', 'name')

  return render(request, 'app/test2.html', { # brings all the data into selected html
    "form": form1,
    "locationList": locationList,
    "clientList": clientList,
    "eventList": eventList,
  })
```

So if e.g. 27-01-2019; Bob Dylan already exists in the db, the form would not be valid to submit

Comment: If duplicates are not desired, you should define a `unique` constraint on the appropriate model field (or combination of fields) to enforce this in the database. Then you can just catch the exception `IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed` on `save()` and deal with it if it happens.

Comment: @EndreBoth sweet that worked. A bit unsure of where to catch the error

Answer (score 0):

in the view you can do something like :

```
name = form1.cleaned_data['name']
week = form1.cleaned_data['week']
E = Event.objects.filter(name=name, week=week)
```

so if len(e) is > 0 then there is an object with the same data in the DB

if len(E) == 0: then add as you need

Comment: You also can use `.exists()` for check just existance.

Comment: Yes Thank you @seuling